# replace repetitive string but at mount point

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to replace mount point name with some name , in this case string `"/filesystem"` is repetitive so my re.sub is replacing at both occurrence however I only want to replace at mount position, in this case at 2nd position , How do I fix it please?

```
re.sub(r"/filesystem", "/Abhimanyu" , "server1.abc.com:/export/admin_01/filesystem /filesystem nfs rw,bg,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,vers=3,timeo=600,noacl 0 0")

In [53]: re.sub(r"/filesystem", "/Abhimanyu" , "server1.abc.com:/export/admin_01/filesystem /filesystem nfs rw,bg,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,vers=3,timeo=600,noacl 0 0")
Out[53]: 'server1.abc.com:/export/admin_01/Abhimanyu /Abhimanyu nfs rw,bg,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,vers=3,timeo=600,noacl 0 0'
```

Comment: Please use code formatting so your content is readable.

Answer (score 1):

Just match the beginning of the string up to first white space character, and then the end from the whitespace following your replaced substring till the end:

```
>>> re.sub(r"^(\S+\s)/filesystem(\s.*$)", r"\1/Abhimanyu\2", "server1.abc.com:/export/admin_01/filesystem /filesystem nfs rw,bg,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,vers=3,timeo=600,noacl 0 0")
'server1.abc.com:/export/admin_01/filesystem /Abhimanyu nfs rw,bg,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,vers=3,timeo=600,noacl 0 0'
```

- `^` matches start of string
- `\s` and `\S` match whitespace and non-whitespace characters respectively
- `$` matches end of string
- `.*` matches zero or more (`*`) any characters (`.`)
- `(` `)` mark a group which may be used in the replace string as `\1`, `\2` etc.

Comment: This worked and Thanks for time.  What does (\s.*$) - is it Whilespace , any character zero or more time and end  with (/filesystem) ?

Comment: `(\s.*$)` is a group of [single whitespace] + [zero or more any] + [end of string]. I've edited the answer to explain the `.*`.